# Configure xforms:select element for 'view' mode

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have next problem, when user looks to the filled form element xforms:select shown as it should be readonly and displays the label of selected item, below is html represenation of the element as it comes to browser

```
    ...
<span 
  id="control-8-control" 
  class="xforms-control xforms-select xforms-incremental xforms-select-appearance-full xforms-static xforms-readonly"
>
    some value1
</span>
    ...
```

, but when user clicks on the text "some value", this texts turns to value of selected item, and looks next way

```
        ...
<span 
 id="control-8-control" 
 class="xforms-control xforms-select xforms-incremental xforms-select-appearance-full xforms-static xforms-readonly"
>
   2WPbzcoW3eoH/1rDCyejaA==
</span>
        ...
```

Obviously some listener is hanging on that element, and changes it's inner-html.

Moreover this behavior can be observed only for **xforms:select** elements with **appearance="full"**

Where can I reconfigure this element behavior?

Comment: And I imagine that you are getting this by creating a form with a checkboxes field in Form Builder, then creating a new instance of that form, selecting a value, and going to the review page?

Comment: I managed to reproduce this; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I didn't reproduce exactly the same problem you had, as I have been testing this on a nightly build, but most likely, the source of the problem is the same: the client sends a value change to the server when you click on the label, while it shouldn't. I fixed this, and the fix will be in the next nightly build. For reference, this is the [bug](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/158) and [commit](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/692baedfb9691f05a8225c66007272701ffc0c28).

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, after I've made the same as you did in commit, everything works fine!